# How to send image to Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

Trying to send image (or any type of file) to telegram bot.
It possible to take blob, convert it to Base64 and POST it?

I've tried to test it via SOAPUI but:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXX/sendDocument
{
"chat_id":XXX,
"document":"R0lGODlhKAAoAMIAAAAAAL6+vgCYAOfn5wAA/wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAoACgAAAPYGLrc/jDKSau9OOvNu19AKIafIxJoioplqL4vyQEwIdw1AWw0fAu52w5D+xlxNeOw0rMdjb6fztJ0PpEp6FJSDQKjqS2kNxigygQ0Do1Om6fc89tNX5vbdPhYnmKb7Xl5Yg00eHSGfipogwyFb3eQh5GPZowgkpiJmgMClgqOmZOibp1xbmWop6h+q5ylEWStkJSzq0ITsX1pWTd3fa6elzkqR1HBwsNWWFnHIMtRUi+vTNFJzysZANe8Nc0PXdLdHQDgOeQt5ObnJY3k7uvs8fLz9PX29/EJADs="
}

In that case response:
```

{
"ok": false,
"error_code": 400,
"description": "Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: Wrong character in the string"
}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You just had to send request with form-data)